# how to use @keyframes moving animation from current position to a fixed in CSS3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

This css3 code , move a item from current position to 100px lower.

```
@keyframes movingtocenter
{
from {top:0%;}
to {top:100px;}
}
```

But i want move my object to CENTER of page.
I have many object on the one page in different locations.
and i want to use this keyframes to move all of them to right-center,in the same position. and can't do this!
anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the parent div covers the entire screen.  You can do this with the following css:

```
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Then you just need to specify the animation on the appropriate div, give it an absolute position and tell it where to go using keyframes.

```
.wrapper div {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: myfirst 5s;
} 

.wrapper div.el1{
    right: 200px;
}

.wrapper div.el2 {
    right: 500px;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {top:0;}
    100% {top: 50%; right: 0;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {top:0;}
    100% {top:50%; right: 0;}
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26YYS/)

Comment: It's not because it fills the screen, It's because of `position` property

Comment: @xDNP, yes, it needs the position property on the wrapper for the absolute positioning to work.  But something like position:relative, for example, would not work as the wrapper would only be as big as its encased elements.

Comment: It does not work well. current position with absolute property will change when keyframe starting.
i think i must use jquary or JS to do this.perhaps ,... because css cant get size of screen ONLINE . or hav not dynamic variable

Comment: @m.gh, didn't you want the current position to change when the keyframe started?  I was under the impression that was the scope of your question.

Comment: oh . i found a bug from your code Loren Posen!
http://jsfiddle.net/26YYS/5/
its work to moving from TOP to center.see fiddle.
i set top position for one of elemnte

Comment: Got it @m.gh!  I updated the code, and this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/26YYS/6/.  Don't forget to vote up if this is what you use.

Answer (score 0):

You missed one property in your element:

```
position:absolute;
```

See this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26YYS/1/)

> ***Note:  Only Some Positioning Styles accept top, left, bottom, etc. properties. See documentation for details.***

Comment: thank . i complete your code.
see please http://jsfiddle.net/26YYS/3/
we have 2 element with different positions .on starting keyframe ,  they are going to top of the screen. i want to they stay in current posiotion (each item) and then go to center of page